# Is there any REST API where I can get IANA Timezone releases updates?

Tags: rest, iana, tzdata

I have been searching for it, however I have only found [a paid Microsoft one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/timezone/get-timezone-iana-version?tabs=HTTP).
I need to know when a new version is released and the only source of that information seems to be [this non restful url](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/?C=M;O=D) that returns an html.

Is there any endpoint/library that quickly returns me the latest tzdata version?

Comment: What makes it non-restful? It's GET request, links and hypermedia, it's as RESTful as it gets.

Comment: You are right, probably REST is not what I meant, I need an API Endpoint when I can get the data with a defined structure, not an HTML that can easily change it.

Comment: Judging from the source of that page, it looks like it hasnt changed in many many years. If you can't find a JSON api, consider just parsing the HTML. Probably more reliable to get something from the real source.